# ffmpeg from chrome native messaging host app not working

Tags: c++, google-chrome, ffmpeg, createprocess, chrome-native-messaging

OK, this is what I got, I'm using native messaging to fire a c++ program from a chrome extension in Windows.
This c++ program (ehost.exe) creates a ffmpeg process for recording the input audio and saving it to mp3.
I do this with the CreateProcess() function
This works perfect when I open ehost.exe myself (double clicking it)
but when I open it from my chrome extension (`chrome.runtime.connectNative()` ), the ffmpeg process opens but ffmpeg writes no output file, as if it didn't have permissions...

Anybody knows why?
This is the ehost.exe code for starting ffmpeg.exe

`static HANDLE startFFmpeg()
    {
        char cmd[] = "C:\Users\moizilla\Desktop\native\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -f dshow -i audio=\"Microphone (High Definition Aud\" -acodec libmp3lame C:\Users\moizilla\Desktop\native\kasdkddfodkadd.mp3";
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
        STARTUPINFO si={0};
        si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
        if(CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)){
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
            return pi.hProcess;
        }
        return NULL;
}`

Comment: Does it make a difference if you're running chrome as admin? 
Have you tried enabling logging in chrome to see if something comes up? 
Also, have you tried running a batch file to run your exe?
Finally, which registry path are you using for your exe?

Comment: I tried to run the batch file and didn't work when running from the chrome extension, just when I run the program myself   
The path of the registry key is HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts

Comment: (1)I was able to run a batch file.
(2) this is my manifest file - 
{
    "name": "com.my_company.my_application",
    "description": "Test",
    "path": "calc.bat",
    "type": "stdio",
 "allowed_origins": [
  "chrome-extension://gohcojocpjkcfgnfgbmambgmohcocejg/"
 ]

Comment: I am not running a bat, I'm running an exe that triggers windows processes

Comment: I am building a screen recorder using ffmepg and nacl, I am confused where to start would love to get your experience